# Google Apps Script switching html files

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm wondering if it is possible with google apps script to display the contents of one html file
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('0');
, within the file have a button, and when the button is pressed it will cause the screen to erase the current information and replace itself with a second html file
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('1');
. *note I am NOT wanting to link to a google document nor another webpage. Simply wanting to know if you can switch between html files within the same script document. If it is possible, my reasoning is to have a "menu" page that will display different topics and keep everthing in one document to be more organized.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Apps Script has a service named HtmlService.  You can create sidebars, dialog boxes, and Web Apps with HtmlService.  The ability to delete and replace HTML is mostly a result of using what is called the DOM.  If you create a sidebar, dialog box, or Web App, it will be a combination of JavaScript, the DOM, CSS, Apps Script code, and HTML.  All of those things are separate things, but the DOM is often confused as being JavaScript, and Apps Script might get confused with JavaScript.  Apps Script uses JavaScript, but Apps Script services are specific to Google products.

Comment: To accomplish what you want, you can use the DOM property `innerHTML`.  [Link to innerHTML information](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not wanting to simply modify the DOM within the html page. What I want to do is start with an initial html file (return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('0');) and using a button within the file, have the page erase the initial model and replace it with another (return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('1');). I know and understand the document object model and altering data with javascript. I just haven't found a way to replace an initial "return" value with GAS other than simply linking to a completely different GAS web app.

Comment: I guess what you want is to make a `google.script.run.myFunctionName()` call, and then handle the return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to an extent. We will imply have a function to grab the information from an HTML file and then write it on the page. If you want to be able to navigate, then each `.html` file you have must have the following function in the `<script></script>`

```
function changePage(page) {
    document.open();   //should work fine without this
    document.write(page);
    document.close();  //should work fine without this
}
```

this bit will handle changing the content of the entire page with new content. Now we need to get that content somehow. This will be done with a function inside of a `.gs` file in your Google Script that looks like this

```
function newPage(page) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(page).getContent()
}
```

Then inside of your page, whenever you want to change to a new one you need to have let's say a button:

```
<button onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(changePage).newPage('success')">Next Page</button>
```

In this case the `newPage()` function expects a string that will say what is the name of the html. So following the logic we will do

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('success').getContent()`
```

once we press that button and once that script finishes and returns the string of an HTML we want, we then use that to set the HTML of the current page.

Here is the full example of how it would work. You can navigate between `Index.html` and `success.html`

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function newPage(page) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(page).getContent()
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

  <script>  
  function changePage(page) {
    document.open();
    document.write(page);
    document.close();
  }
  </script>

  <body>
  First Page
    <button onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(changePage).newPage('success')">Next Page</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**success.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>  
  <script>  
  function changePage(page) {
    document.open();
    document.write(page);
    document.close();
  }
  </script>
  <body>
    It worked!
    <button onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(changePage).newPage('Index')">First Page</button>
  </body>
</html>
```