# How to launch a second HTML form using Google Scripts / Google Web app

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to build web app based on Google Sheets.
But for the interaction with user I need more then one HTML page.
The first one is easy to get:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}
```

But based on the response from the first page, I need to show the second page for detailed information.
For example: the first page is for log-in; the second page is for ordering.
How to run the:

```
HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index2');
```

Any help appreciated.

Peter

Comment: Multipage webapp example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55770563/7215091

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking to another HTML page in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668119/linking-to-another-html-page-in-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thank You a lot! I found answers for the same problem; for me the most clear are: [link] 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879144/google-app-more-than-one-html-or-script-file-in-the-the-same-app-project?noredirect=1&lq=1
and [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156292/google-apps-script-switching-html-files?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Add page to query string.

```
function doGet(e) {
  if(e.paramenter.page) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(e.parameter.page);
  }else{
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
  }

}
```